# Shadow trembles when moving cursor close to boxes border

Tags: css, css-transitions

First you sould look at the [final effect](http://jsfiddle.net/WRBQA/3/); it's diffcult to describe. It seems perfect, but there is a little problem.

When your cursor moves close to the square's left border in very small steps, the white shadow also trembles a lot.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `overflow: hidden` on the *#container* div.

The *#shadow* div is overflowing to the left, expanding the *hoverable* area from its parent.

```
#container{
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```